# WSL: command work manually but not in cron

Tags: files, cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux, touch-command

This command work manually in WSL Ubuntu but not in cron. Manually it is:

```
touch /var/www/html/myFile.sh
```

By cron every minute it is:

```
* * * * * touch /var/www/html/myFile.sh
```

Why it's not effective when in cron?

Comment: I don't think WSL starts the cron service by default - have you done so manually?

Comment: Oh, you were right. It doesn't. When I've got it started with `service cron start` it did and the file was creatred successfully. Thanks!

Comment: @steeldriver  answer please :-)

Comment: @Rinzwind - done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSL does not provide a complete Ubuntu environment by default - in particular, it may not start all the conventional system services. At least at the time of writing this answer, `cron` seems to be one of those, as discussed in this [/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/) thread

[Crontab Not Working with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/5jpyyf/crontab_not_working_with_bash_on_ubuntu_on_windows/dbieaf3/)

The suggested solution is to start the service manually: on WSL that is done<sup>1</sup> by

```
service cron start
```

---

<sup>1</sup> despite being based on Ubuntu 16.04, WSL does not appear to use `systemd`